"2nd derivative" Mean value theorem
I have been studying about Taylor Series and Remainder stuff and came across this:
$$ \exists c \in (a,x): f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + f''(c)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} $$
I don't know what are the conditions for this $ c $ to exist, and i also don't know how to prove it.
I tried many functions to apply Roll's theorem but no results.
I also want to know is there an official name for this "mean value theorem"
I searched everywhere but i only find little to no information about this.

The key phrase is "Taylor's Theorem". Try looking up Taylor's Theorem, which is essentially just a higher-order mean value theorem.

The last term is the remainder of the "Taylor Theorem with Remainder."
